# Pygame Lightning animation using pygame.timer.set_timer()

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently trying to produce an animation of lightning using pygame. I planned to have the lightning animation occur every 3 seconds using the pygame.timer.set_timer() module since I will have other animations occurring that are independent of the lightning animation.

For simplicity, I symbolized the lightning with a yellow triangle that elongates. Once it reaches past a certain point, I planned for the yellow triangle to stop, disappear for 3 seconds, before reoccurring again.

However, the lightning_event does not seem to be triggered every time within the while loop, and there is no delay happening.

I have looked at the invaders example using pygame.timer.set_timer(), although it does not use xy coordinates. I tried adjusting the invaders code to use xy coordinates, but it did not work either.

Another question I have is that if there is many events occurring at once, is using multithreading or multiprocessing a better option than using pygame.timer.set_timer()? If so, how can multithreading or multiprocessing be used with the pygame module? Especially because of python's GIL?

Here is my code for the lighting animation:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
YELLOW = (200,240,70)

size = (700,500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Multithreading Project")

done = False

delay1 = 3000 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def lightning(y_coord,y_coord_incr):
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen,YELLOW,[[200,200],[100,y_coord],[300,y_coord]])

lightning_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(lightning_event, delay1)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == lightning_event:
            if y_coord > 500:
                y_coord = 200
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    lightning(y_coord,y_coord_incr)
    y_coord = y_coord + y_coord_incr
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

Thank you!

Comment: I tried your code. Declarations of `y_coord` and `y_coord_incr` are missing, but besides that, the event is triggered every 3 seconds, like it should. Try adding a simple `print` statement inside the `elif event.type == lightning_event:` to see it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a boolean variable (I called it `lightning_anim_playing`) and set it to `True` to start the animation.

While the animation is playing, increment the `y_coord` and draw the lightning.

Once the y_coord is greater than 500, start the timer for the next lightning (`pygame.time.set_timer(lightning_event, delay1)`) and set the boolean variable to `False` to stop the animation.

When the timer is done, stop it (`pygame.time.set_timer(lightning_event, 0)`), reset the y_coord and set the boolean variable to `True` again to start the next animation.

```
import pygame


WHITE = (255,255,255)
YELLOW = (200,240,70)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

delay1 = 3000
lightning_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(lightning_event, delay1)
y_coord = 200
y_coord_incr = 3
lightning_anim_playing = False

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == lightning_event:
            pygame.time.set_timer(lightning_event, 0)  # Stop the timer.
            lightning_anim_playing = True  # Start the animation.
            y_coord = 200  # Reset the y_coord.

    if lightning_anim_playing:
        # Update the y_coord.
        y_coord += y_coord_incr
        if y_coord > 500:
            # Stop the animation.
            lightning_anim_playing = False
            # Start the timer for the next lightning.
            pygame.time.set_timer(lightning_event, delay1)

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    # Draw the lightning if the animation is playing.
    if lightning_anim_playing:
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen,YELLOW,[[200,200],[100,y_coord],[300,y_coord]])

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! Do you know what was wrong with the logic of my original program?

Comment: After adjusting the value of the delay1 and the y value of 500 in the if statement, I noticed that the lightning event already occurred in the main loop. However, there is no delay yet. As the y_coord goes past 500, the if statement is triggered, and the y_coord is set back to 200. However, the pygame.timer.set_timer is triggered for 3 seconds and the animation continues for 3 additional seconds before restarting.

Comment: I noticed that if the delay1 was small enough, the lightning_event may be triggered several times in the main loop before the  lightning animation goes past the y_coord of 500. One example would be to set delay1 = 10 and the maximum y_coord to 300 instead of 500. By printing both the lightning event in the event.type in the for loop and when the y_coord exceeds 300, you can see that the  lightning_event happens several times before the y_coord exceeds 300.   May you explain what is going on within the lightning_event and pygame delay in the event loop in the main loop?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the new problem, so please tell me what exactly should be happening and what's going wrong (also seeing your code would probably help). The timer in my example just controls the time between two lightnings. The animation time depends on the `y_coord_incr` the `if y_coord > 500:` statement and the frame rate. If the animation should take exactly three seconds, you either need a second timer or have to adjust the `y_coord_incr` so that it reaches the target in the desired time.

Comment: *"I noticed that if the delay1 was small enough, the lightning_event may be triggered several times"* - If the delay1 is shorter than the delta time (the time between two `clock.tick` calls which is 16.6 period ms with 60 FPS) then sometimes two of the lighting_events will be added to the queue in the same frame. If that shouldn't happen, you need a larger delay time.

Comment: My problem was actually with the logic of my original code (The code I posted for my question). Do you know where my logic went wrong in the code, so the lightning animation did not work like it was supposed to? From what I have seen, it seems like the lightning_event is triggered before the lightning animation starts, and after the lightning animation goes past y_coord = 500, the pygame timer starts. After the 3 seconds have passed, then the y_coord is reset to 200 and the lightning animation restarts.

Answer (score 0):

You very rarely want to use multiprocessing or multithreading. For any graphical related code, it should be run in the main thread. Multiprocessing/multithreading only comes along if you're trying to load up or process large amounts of data while still keeping the window responsive. If you use other libraries such as for networking (twisted reactor) that have their own mainloop you can hijack their mainloop since pygame does not have a built in mainloop.

Pygame also has a more sequential api for handling events and you process all recent events before drawing to the screen so when events occur at the same time, you process them sequentially but any visual difference is seen once the screen is updated. The routine of fetching any recent events, handling them followed by updating the screen every frame is a rule of thumb for when making a Pygame app. Implementing multithreading/multiprocessing will usually reduce or have no effect on the performance of your program, all the while making it substantially more difficult to program and build upon. For animations you can also use timestamps using `import time ; time.time()` which allows you to not be restricted to pygame clock. As long as CPU intensive code is kept to a minimal between event fetch and draw cycles there is no reason to overcomplicate your code. You can always test your program during runtime for FPS drops to then selectively optimise your code.

As a side note, Pygame should not be used to make complicated games, more as a learning tool to develop your skills since Pygame is a somewhat limited and outdated package. For example, having multiple displays is tedious and is usually accomplished with multiprocessing, the Pygame event handler often does not give as much information as necessary (scroll wheel movement amount). A good alternative is Pyglet but is quite daunting to use at first.